# Creating multiple variables yacc

Tags: variables, yacc

I am creating a compiler in yacc but I cannot find a way to allow the user to create multiple variables with individual identifiers.  Currently they can assign a number to a word but all words have the same value.  The code I'm using it:

```
...

%{
float var=0;
%}

...

exp: NUMBER 
   | WORD { $$ = var; }
   | exp '/' exp {  $$ = $1 / $3; }
   | ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex/Lex - How do I know if a variable was declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284546/flex-lex-how-do-i-know-if-a-variable-was-declared)

Answer (score 0):

`$$` will assign to the `exp` token the value `var`. So this is static.

If you want to parse some `WORD` and get its value, you should use `$$ = $1` where $1 is the value of the first token of your rule (*id est* the WORD token)

Is that what you intended to do? I'm not sure about that, since you've done it right for the `exp '/' exp` ?

EDIT: To store each word in variable, I'd suggest you to use a table of floats.
You will need to use a counter to increment the table index. But you should take care that the different words values will be stored in the matching order.

EDIT2:
(Don't know if it will compile as is)
I think it would look like :

```
exp: NUMBER
   | variable AFFECT exp { $$ = $3; var[ctr][0]="$1"; var[ctr][1]=$3; ctr++; }
   | variable { $$ = lookupVar($1); }
```

And define lookupVar to look for the string $1 within the table

Comment: A single variable works as shown above, I'm tyring to get it working so the user can create multiple variables so each `WORD` is a different variable.

Comment: But don't you read the WORD value from the input you are parsing?

Comment: That's my question, how do you save the value assigned with the `WORD` to be referred to later.

Comment: How do I call the saved values later? As in, if the user types `test = var + 5` How would I reference them?

Comment: Could you complete your parser rules in your post to help me understand what you are parsing?

Comment: The rest of the rules are irrelevant, all I need to know is how I recall the variable with reference to the users name for it after it is saved to the vars array.

Comment: I think I'm lost. What are the usernames? Do you parse them? I think a more detailed scenario would really help me.

Comment: OK. What I am trying to do is allow the user to create multiple variables so they can reference them later on by a `WORD` where a word is a sting of characters.  The code above allows users to save variables to a word though, the reference is not unique.  Therefore, no matter what word the user uses it is always the same value.

Comment: oh you mean you are parsing a calculus and you want to add the use of variable? Ok let me think about that.

Comment: Yes, sort of.  I want it to work like other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be similar to `mfcalc` sample in
[bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Multi_002dfunction-Calc).
Probably `mfcalc` sample will provide useful information, even if it isn't
fully identical to your purpose.
`mfcalc` has a symbol table in order to keep the names of `VAR`(probably
corresponds to `WORD` in your code).
Actually `mfcalc` enforces symbol name look-up in lexical analysis, and assigns
a pointer to symbol record, to the semantic value of `VAR`.
In bison source code, the semantic value can be referred simply as like
`$1->value.var`.
Hope this helps