# Flex/Lex - How to know if a variable was declared

Tags: variables, yacc, flex-lexer

My grammar allows:

C → id := E   // assign a value/expression to a variable (VAR)

C → print(id) // print variables(VAR) values

To get it done, my lex file is:

```
[a-z]{
    yylval.var_index=get_var_index(yytext);
    return VAR;
}
```

get_var_index returns the index of the variable in the list, if it does not exist then it creates one.
It is working!

The **problem** is:

- Everytime a variable is matched on lex file it creates a index to that variable.
- I have to report if  'print(a)' is called and 'a' was not declared, and that will never happen since print(a) always creates an index to 'a'.*

**How can I solve it?**

Piece of yacc file:

```
   %union {
int     int_val;
int var_index;
} 
%token <int_val>   INTEGER
%token <var_index>   VAR
...
| PRINT '(' VAR ')'{
 n_lines++;
printf("%d\n",values[$3]);
}
...
| VAR {$$ =values[$1];}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem a bit like a Computer Science class homework question for us to do.

Normally one would not use bison/yacc in this way. One would do the parse with bison/yacc and make a parse tree which then gets walked to perform semantic checks, such as checking for declaration before use and so on. The identifiers would normally be managed in a symbol table, rather than just a table of values to enable other attributes, such as *declared* to be managed. It's for these reasons that it looks like an exercise rather than a realistic application of the tools. OK; those disclaimers disposed of, lets get to an answer.

The problem would be solved by remembering what has been declared and what not. If one does not plan to use a full symbol table then a simple array of *booleans* indicating which are the valid values could be used. The array can be initialised to *false* and set to *true* on declaration. This value can be checked when a variable is used. As **C** uses ints for *boolean* we can use that. The only changes needed are in the bison/yacc. You omitted any syntax for the declarations, but as you indicated they are declared there must be some. I guessed.

```
%union {
int     int_val;
int var_index;
} 
int [MAX_TABLE_SIZE] declared; /* initialize to zero before starting parse */
%token <int_val>   INTEGER
%token <var_index>   VAR
...
| DECLARE '(' VAR ')' { n_lines++; declared[$3] = 1; }
...
| PRINT '(' VAR ')'{
 n_lines++;
if (declared[$3]) printf("%d\n",values[$3]);
else printf("Variable undeclared\n");
}
...
| VAR {$$ =value[$1]; /* perhaps need to show more syntax to show how VAR used */}
```